# Swift - add custom color from Storyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, colors

I have a custom made color in Storyboard. Is there a way to access it via code? Couldn't find anything on that topic.

[image]

I know there is a way to code custom-colors in Swift like this:

view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.00)

But getting my exact color with that method will take ages. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I got it working with the RGB slider but my collectionView still appears white. That's my code:

```
    let theCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let v = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 50, green: 215, blue: 200, alpha: 1)
    v.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return v
}()
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `UIColor init?(named:)` initializer?

Comment: I edited my post. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just look at your color using the sliders tab. Then you'll know the RGB values without any guessing.

Comment: whats the sliders tab?

Comment: At the top of the color picker, there are icons for color wheel, sliders, etc.  Choose the second one from the left, and then choose **RGB Sliders** from the pop up.

Comment: Another way to get your color, start a comment in your code by typing `// ` and then drag and drop the color patch from the picker into that comment, and you will see something like `// #colorLiteral(red: 0.444444, green: 1.0, blue: 0.5555, alpha: 1)`

Comment: wait, its not working. My collectionView doesnt change the color

Comment: Those values need to be divided by `255.0` because the range is `0...1` not `0...255`: `UIColor(red: 50.0/255.0, green: 215.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 1)`

Comment: working now, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of ways to do this.

1. Drag the color patch directly into the code.  This will add a `#colorLiteral` which will show as a little colored patch right in the code.  Clicking on the color patch will open the color picker.  If you want to see the values for the `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha`, just comment out that line of code.
2. You can view the color using the **RGB Sliders** in the color picker.  Choose the *Sliders* icon (second from the left) and choose **RGB Sliders** from the popup.  To put the RGB values into your code, you need to divide the values by `255.0` because the range needed by `UIColor` is `0...1` not `0...255`.  So for `RGBA(50, 215, 200, 1)`, the value would be:

   ```
   UIColor(red: 50.0/255.0, green: 215.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
   ```